# Fragment Login issues with Facebook 3.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to login using a fragment in Facebook 3.0. I created an image button in my fragment which responds to an on click method as shown below :

OnCreateView and OnClickView code :

```
   @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle saved){

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mefrag, group, false);
    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.facebooklogin); 
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            loginToFacebook();

        }
    });
    return v;

}
```

The logintoFacebook method does not start the next activity. It just shows the fb dialog, accepts my details and then shows the fragment again. I tested this code in a separate activity and it works fine, i just can't figure out why it isn't working here.

Facebook Login Code:

public void loginToFacebook(){

```
    Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

      @Override
      public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {

            Log.d("LOGIN", "activated session");
          // make request to the /me API
          Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            // callback after Graph API response with user object
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
              if (user != null) {

                Log.d("LOGIN", "activated on complete");

                  fbuserid = user.getId();
                  fbusername = user.getFirstName();  

                  SharedPreferences fbDetails = getActivity().
                      getSharedPreferences("fbDetails", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = fbDetails.edit();
                  editor.putString(FB_USER, user.getFirstName());
                  editor.putString(FB_ID,user.getId());  
                  editor.putBoolean("logged in", true);
                  editor.commit();


                 loginFacebookKinveyUser();


                  Intent i = new 
                        Intent("com.example.chartviewer.MyArtistsActivity");


                  startActivityForResult(i, 1);

              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });

}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you overriding onActivityResult, and calling Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult()?

Comment: @MingLi hi i need some help...i want to know how to handle onActivityResult for facebook requestMeAsync() when there are some other activities that has been started for result??

Comment: You don't need to handle onActivityResult for requestMeAsync calls, only for session opening and requesting new permissions via the Session class. So if the code you posted is in your Activity class, you should override onActivityResult, and call Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult. Otherwise your callback will never get called.